# Keeping gpg signature in git patches with format-patch

Tags: git, github, gnupg, gpg-signature

I generally sign my commits with gpg keys. However, there are certain times that I need to send my patches through email, which I achieve by using `git-format-patch` and `git-send-email`. However, this results in my GPG signatures removed from the patch. My goal is to have someone else actually apply the patches to repository and send it, also preserving my signature so authenticity of the code is ensured.

By using `git-am`, the committer is creating a new hash, thus new commit So I'm not certain that the signature would even work I'm not sure what goes into gpg for signing, only the diff, maybe? If that's the case, I guess this would work. Is this possible?

I've looked at git documentation on `git-format-patch` and It seems there's a `--signature` option, which is not very well documented, I've tried doing a couple of things to attach a signature to patches, but none of them survived into the destination git repository. What's the correct way of using it?

And finally, even if adding `--signature` achieves what I'm trying achieve, it might be cumbersome when creating a series of patches and sending them via email. Is there a batch option that simply attaches the signature which I can clearly see attached to commits with `git cat-file -p <HASH>`, to the patches generated with `git-format-patch`?

Thanks

Comment: This may help, https://mikegerwitz.com/papers/git-horror-story

Comment: I've read that one, (It's one of the articles that pop up at the first search, really). This article however, takes the exact opposite approach of what I've been trying to achieve. You can see clearly the author is not in support of signing wth GPG keys if you're a contributor to a project. He suggests using `Signed-off-by:` which doesn't really do the same thing. It's popular among gnu/linux kernel contributors, but not that widely used. 
Anyway, my goal is not adding `Signed-off-by`, but actually signing with gpg.

Comment: I tried some gpg tests. I don't think it's reasonable that `git am` preserves the signature. The signature is made with the private key. If someone else runs `git am` with your patch, a new commit object is created. This object is not created by you, so it's not reasonable that it has your signature. Your private key is not leaked so the new object's creator can't use your private key to sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think `git-format-patch` can preserve signatures. You may try `git bundle`; it certainly preserves everything; but it's not as convenient to send over email.